# Using more than one != in an if statement

Tags: marketing-cloud

When I use more than one != in an if statement, it doesn't seem to work.

eg.

```
%%[IF @country != "UK" OR @Membership != "USA" THEN]%%...
```

It seems to just ignore the second one.

Comment: Put them in brackets

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing OR with AND? AND means both statements must be true, while OR means that only one of the two options needs to be true.

Answer (score 0):

You should put them in brackets

```
%%[IF (@country != "UK" OR @Membership != "USA" )THEN]%%
```

Comment: no need of brackets Ampscript `if condition` works without the brackets.